# While loop not running same as it does in other file with same code

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops, cron

I am creating cron jobs where a user will receive an email and sms notification and when I run the loop in email it works fine. But for the sms it does not. Only first row in data table is running.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM testloop";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      
      $name = $row["name"];
      $number = $row['number'];
      
      
    // echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $name. " " . $number. "<br>";
    // SMS gateway starts here
    // Configure HTTP basic authorization: BasicAuth
    $config = ClickSend\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()
    ->setUsername('myusername')
    ->setPassword('addPassword');

    $apiInstance = new ClickSend\Api\SMSApi(new GuzzleHttp\Client(),$config);
    $msg = new \ClickSend\Model\SmsMessage();
    $msg->setBody("$name Complete Your Profile Now. Sms Notification"); 
    $msg->setTo($number);
    $msg->setSource("sdk");
    
    // \ClickSend\Model\SmsMessageCollection | SmsMessageCollection model
    $sms_messages = new \ClickSend\Model\SmsMessageCollection();
    $sms_messages->setMessages([$msg]);
    
    try {
        $result = $apiInstance->smsSendPost($sms_messages);
        print_r($result);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Exception when calling SMSApi->smsSendPost: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
    }
    
  }
  
  
}

    
?>
```

The sms is using clicksend api. The same loop is for email which is working fine, I'm replacing send email part with sms only.

In error log :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on string
```

I tried some solutions from google search but non helped.

Comment: You overwrite your $result variable here `$result = $apiInstance->smsSendPost($sms_messages);` for the next iteration at `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()` $result is a string. Which the error message tells you.

Comment: Do you really need to instantiate the class in every iteration? This seems like unnecessary overhead.